# How To Translate Delphi record struct to C# and get data from the struct

Tags: c#, delphi, record

I recently doing some work on a dll call.the dll was to communicate with a com object.In the Help File ,the Examples were written in Delphi .There was an Event Named `OnOperatorInfoMsg`, First call a Method Named `MethodA`，then It raise the Event，the event returns what defined  in delphi was below:

```
OnOperatorInfoMsg = procedure(Sender: TObject; wOperatorCount: Integer; OperatorsInfo: Integer) of object;
```

and through the dnspy,I find the Event was Translated to C# Like this:

```
  public class OnOperatorInfoMsgEvent
{
    public int wOperatorCount;
    public int operatorsInfo;

    public OnOperatorInfoMsgEvent(int wOperatorCount, int operatorsInfo);
}
```

and the OperatorsInfo in delphi defines like this:

```
OPINFO
OPINFO = record 
   wAgentID: WORD; 
   wSkillGroupID: WORD;
   wWorkGroupID: WORD; 
   AgentStatus: AGENT_STATUS; 
end;
```

How can I get the wAgentID、wSkillGroupID、AgentStatus in the OperatorsInfo  from C#?

Comment: There's not remotely enough detail here to answer. You'll need to edit the question significantly. But I can say that the Delphi type `TCccCtrlXOnOperatorInfoMsg` has no easy interop friendly definition in C#. Assuming of course that you are indeed doing pinvoke interop between your C# host executable and your Delphi DLL. But even that is guesswork.

Comment: This is at least two questions and possibly more.  Your translation of `TCccCtrlXOnOperatorInfoMsg` is entirely incorrect - it is not a class, it's a method reference (and, as @DavidHeffernan notes, not one that C# can consume).  You have `OperatorsInfo: Integer` in the first example but then it seems that in the last you're suggesting that it is a record and not an int.

Comment: I just updated the question？Could u help me again,please?

Comment: The update is really no better. The question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem was solved in Huawei Dev BBS：
http://developer.huawei.com/ict/forum/thread-23981-1-1.html